# Replace a column value using AWK

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

I have a file named as **source-data.lst** (created using ls -l) which contains the following information:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 soumyadipd soumyadipd 379 Apr  2 17:07 filegen.awk
-rw-rw-r-- 1 soumyadipd soumyadipd 129 Mar 31 13:35 file_name_list.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 soumyadipd soumyadipd 624 Apr  2 16:32 log
-rw-r--r-- 1 soumyadipd root         0 Apr  3 12:38 source-data.lst
-rw-rw-r-- 1 soumyadipd soumyadipd 676 Apr  2 16:32 temp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 soumyadipd soumyadipd 157 Mar 31 15:10 Type1_LP_OUT.txt
```

I need to update the file size by 1 for every row.

by executing `awk '{ $5=$5+1; print $0 }' source-data.lst` from terminal the output will be as follows:

```
[soumyadipd@linuxpc awkscripts]$ awk '{ $5=$5+1; print $0 }' source-data.lst
-rwxrwxrwx 1 soumyadipd soumyadipd 380 Apr 2 17:07 filegen.awk
-rw-rw-r-- 1 soumyadipd soumyadipd 130 Mar 31 13:35 file_name_list.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 soumyadipd soumyadipd 625 Apr 2 16:32 log
-rw-r--r-- 1 soumyadipd root 1 Apr 3 12:38 source-data.lst
-rw-rw-r-- 1 soumyadipd soumyadipd 677 Apr 2 16:32 temp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 soumyadipd soumyadipd 158 Mar 31 15:10 Type1_LP_OUT.txt
[soumyadipd@linuxpc awkscripts]$
```

But the problem is that I have an AWK script named as **filegen.awk** as:

```
BEGIN{
      noOfSourceData=0;
    while ((getline data < "source-data.lst") > 0) {
        noOfSourceData++;
        sourceRecordsList[noOfSourceData] = data;
    }
}{

}END{
for (sd=1; sd<= noOfSourceData; sd++) {
#print sourceRecordsList[sd]
print sourceRecordsList[sd] > "temp"
awk '{ $5=$5+1; print $0 }' temp
}
}
```

Using this **filegen.awk** I have to increase the file size of **source-data.lst**. So executing the script as follows I found the following error:

```
[soumyadipd@linuxpc awkscripts]$ awk -f filegen.awk source-data.lst > log
awk: filegen.awk:16: awk '{ $5=$5+1; print $0 }' temp
awk: filegen.awk:16:     ^ invalid char ''' in expression
[soumyadipd@linuxpc awkscripts]$
```

Kindly help me to make a solution... thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you need this for? [Don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: using the output of ls -l is just an example. You may consider any file with tabular data as:

1 Soumyadip Das 29 India
2 Mr. Bill 46 USA
3 Mr. XYZ 34 GB

Comment: Don't call `awk` inside an awk script.

Comment: You are trying to execute `awk` from within `awk`, that obviously doesn't work.

Comment: @ Lutz Horn and @ Adrian Frühwirth : then what to do ?

Comment: Use the *content* of your own one-liner inside the existing script.

Comment: sorry, your comment is not clear to me.

Comment: @SoumyadipDas I don't know if you pasted the entire `filegen.awk` here. I guess you didn't. since the impl. in the script is just **too** complicated. basically it just print out every line of that `lst` file (without your newly added awk line), the `while`, the `for`....  if the script was the entire thing. it could be written in one single line.

Comment: @Kent Its the part of a big thing, and I have an array contains values as shown in .lst file (every row of .lst is an array element). I have to change the value of a column as described. So I created this example to make this easier.

Comment: The solution you posted is not even close to a reasonable solution for the problem you stated above so we may as well close this question because as stated it must not reflect what you're really trying to do.

Comment: @EdMorton No problem if admin close this question, because I got my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, and the code of **filegen.awk** is as follows:

```
BEGIN{
    noOfSourceData=0;
    while ((getline data < "source-data.lst") > 0) {
        noOfSourceData++;
        sourceRecordsList[noOfSourceData] = data;
    }
}{

}END{
for (sd=1; sd<= noOfSourceData; sd++) {
system("echo \"" sourceRecordsList[sd] "\" | awk '{ $5=$5+1; print $0 }'");
}
}
```

And I get little idea from [here](http://goo.gl/TDDn9r) while searching for the solution.

Thanks everybody for replying.

Comment: That script makes no sense. Why are you writing a getline loop to do what awk does naturally? Why are you using awk to create an array to pass to system to invoke shell to call echo to use a pipeline to invoke awk instead of simply modifying each input line in the original awk script as it's read? What is wrong with just `awk '$5+=1' source-data.lst`?

Comment: @EdMorton **Please first read the full question and answers and comments and everything and after that ask about your confusion.** Previously I made a comment as: `"Its the part of a big thing, and I have an array contains values as shown in .lst file (every row of .lst is an array element). I have to change the value of a column as described. So I created this example to make this easier."` First of all try to understand the real problem.

Comment: There is nothing posted anywhere on this page, question or comment, that would lead to your posting being the right solution. Either there's something you haven't told us or you have come up with the wrong solution. I've been developing in awk for 20+ years, shell for 30+, and I can't imagine what kind of problem would lead to the solution you posted being in any way reasonable but if you're happy with it then good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `getline` into a variable `getline data < "source-data.lst"` you could use just `getline` from a file:

```
awk '
BEGIN{
    noOfSourceData=0;
    while ((getline < "source-data.lst") > 0) {
        noOfSourceData++;
        $5=$5+1;
        sourceRecordsList[noOfSourceData] = $0;
    }
}
{

}

END{
    for (sd=1; sd<= noOfSourceData; sd++)
        print sourceRecordsList[sd]
}' dummy.txt
```

Comment: I am not looking for this answer. My problem is different.

Comment: @SoumyadipDas Ok, what is then the problem with this answer?

Comment: @SoumyadipDas Ok, great!